# Using having count() in exists clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to make a SQL query where the subquery in an 'exists' clause has a 'having' clause. The strange thing is that. There is no error and the subquery works as a stand-alone query. However, the whole query gives exactly the same results with the 'having' clause as without.
This is kind of what my query looks like:

```
 SELECT X
   FROM A
  WHERE exists (
               SELECT X, count(distinct Y)
                 FROM B
             GROUP BY X
               HAVING count(distinct Y) > 2)
```

So I'm trying to select the rows from A where X has more then two occurances of Y in B.
However, the results also include records that do not exist in the subquery. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't correlate the two queries:

```
SELECT  X
FROM    A
WHERE   (
        SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT y)
        FROM    b
        WHERE   b.x = a.x
        ) > 2
```

Comment: Ah yes, that sounds like a good idea. I'll look into correlating queries. I think it's going to help me solve this further :)

Answer (score 4):

Your query says something like this:

select X from A IF THERE ARE records having more than one occurence if grouped by Y in B.

If your 'exists subquery' returns even one record from table B the condition is true and you will get all the rows from A.

Try:

```
select X
from A
where exists (select 1
              from B
              where B.x = A.x
              group by b.x
              having count(distinct b.y) > 2
             )
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation and solved by a JOIN since the other answers didn't work for me.  I tried to correlate to your generic example.  Hope it is helpful to someone else!

```
SELECT  X
FROM    A
JOIN (SELECT X, COUNT(DISTINCT y)
      FROM B
      GROUP BY X
      HAVING count(distinct Y) > 2) C
ON A.X = C.X
```