# SQL Subquery Having COUNT(var) turns 0 to NULLs

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, subquery

I have written a SQL query with a subquery to include counts. When the count is 0, and I try to filter out the 0, it turns the 0's to NULLs and keeps the rows, and vice versa. The result is that I can't filter out the 0's, which was the purpose of including the counts.

```
 SELECT  distinct      
         a
        ,b
        ,
     (SELECT  
        count(id)
        FROM seq_stud
        WHERE scs.SequenceID = seq_stud.SequenceID
       and seq_stud.EndDate is null 
      HAVING count(id) <> 0 
      ) As t1   
    FROM sp 
    INNER JOIN p on sp.ProgramID = p.ProgramID  
    ...etc.
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can filter out the 0 counts?

Comment: You are select a count of "ID" but are restricting on the Having statement a count of "STUDENTID".  Is that intentional?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you probably need to put WHERE t1 > 0 in the final WHERE clause.  You may not need the HAVING at all.

Comment: that was a mistake - i changed both to be id now

Answer (score 0):

You don't filter in the `SELECT` clause.  If you don't want rows that have no match in `seq_stud`, then use `WHERE`:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM seq_stud ss
              WHERE scs.SequenceID = ss.SequenceID and ss.EndDate is null 
             )
```

Comment: I tried this but it's giving me an error. How would I include the WHERE EXISTS within the subquery

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the HAVING statement altogether.  You need to put that in the WHERE clause.  Otherwise, it will return null, as you found.

```
SELECT  distinct a, b, 
   (SELECT count(id)
    FROM seq_stud
    WHERE scs.SequenceID = seq_stud.SequenceID
       and seq_stud.EndDate is null 
   ) As t1   
FROM sp 
INNER JOIN p on sp.ProgramID = p.ProgramID  

WHERE t1 > 0
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I get the error that t1 is an invalid column name.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out. The Select subquery should be included as a WHERE statement

[Using having count() in exists clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849731/using-having-count-in-exists-clause)